# Why is my XML List not parsed when parsing with Jackson?

Tags: java, xml, jackson

is there anyone who can help me why my currencyCubeList is null? I think i have a missunderstanding with the List CubeList.
I am Using Spring Boot with Jackson and Lombok. I also tried to add the List to the MainCube but this also will result in null.
[image]

```
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
<gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
<gesmes:Sender>
    <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
</gesmes:Sender>
<Cube>
    <Cube time="2022-05-06">
        <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.0570"/>
        <Cube currency="JPY" rate="137.90"/>
        <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
        <Cube currency="CZK" rate="24.665"/>
        <Cube currency="DKK" rate="7.4400"/>
        <Cube currency="GBP" rate="0.85625"/>
        <Cube currency="HUF" rate="381.47"/>
        <Cube currency="PLN" rate="4.7028"/>
        <Cube currency="RON" rate="4.9490"/>
        <Cube currency="SEK" rate="10.4686"/>
        <Cube currency="CHF" rate="1.0419"/>
        <Cube currency="ISK" rate="138.30"/>
        <Cube currency="NOK" rate="9.9808"/>
        <Cube currency="HRK" rate="7.5336"/>
        <Cube currency="TRY" rate="15.8078"/>
        <Cube currency="AUD" rate="1.4888"/>
        <Cube currency="BRL" rate="5.3183"/>
        <Cube currency="CAD" rate="1.3560"/>
        <Cube currency="CNY" rate="7.0506"/>
        <Cube currency="HKD" rate="8.2969"/>
        <Cube currency="IDR" rate="15312.44"/>
        <Cube currency="ILS" rate="3.5965"/>
        <Cube currency="INR" rate="81.2980"/>
        <Cube currency="KRW" rate="1343.90"/>
        <Cube currency="MXN" rate="21.3555"/>
        <Cube currency="MYR" rate="4.6191"/>
        <Cube currency="NZD" rate="1.6440"/>
        <Cube currency="PHP" rate="55.467"/>
        <Cube currency="SGD" rate="1.4642"/>
        <Cube currency="THB" rate="36.303"/>
        <Cube currency="ZAR" rate="16.9614"/>
    </Cube>
</Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

Envelope.java

```
@Data
public class Envelope {
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Cube")
private MainCube mainCube;
}
```

MainCube.java

```
@Data
public class MainCube {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Cube")
    private Cube cube;
}
```

Cube.java (until here it works)

```
@Data
public class Cube {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "time", isAttribute = true)
    private String time;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Cube")
    List<CurrencyCube> currencyCubeList;
}
```

CurrencyCube.java

```
@Data
public class CurrencyCube {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "rate", isAttribute = true)
    private Double rate;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "currency", isAttribute = true)
    private String currency;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could resolve it by using `useWrapping=false` in the Annotation obove the list

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Cube")
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
List<CurrencyCube> currencyCubeList;
```